# Is the entanglement of mixed states meaningful?

Tags: quantum-information

For mixed 2-partite states, the entanglement of formation (EoF) is defined by the convex roof of all its possible decompositions. Since density matrix is not a complete description of a mixed state, is the entanglement defined above has a physical meaning? In the ER=EPR configuration, the geometry of the ER bridge is dependent on the exact pattern of the entanglement. For a mixed state, there is no 'exact' entanglement pattern and the geometry should be dependent on a specific purification of the mixed state. So at least we can say nothing about the ERB structure between two blackholes which are formed by collapsing two sets of entangled particles in mixed states, since the geometry should be dependent on its specific purification? Does this mean the the EOF of mixed state is not physical?

Comment: When writing a question, always define acronyms before using them.

Comment: What do you mean by "Since density matrix is not a complete description of a mixed state"?

Comment: I mean density is some tool tailored for computing the 'expectation' of observables. But it does not specify the 'state' of a mixed state as the wave function does for a pure state. For me density matrix is a kind of 'coarse grained' description like a point in the base space of a fibre bundle structure. It can not specify all the details of the state but only describe the state by 'expectated' values. Is it true?

Comment: No, this is not true.  The density matrix provides a complete description of a system in a mixed state. The density matrix is as physical as it gets. -- Unless, of course, you are in fact thinking of a part of a larger system, and you do not want to disregard the large system.  P.S.: Unless you use @[username] in your comment, I don't get notified of it.

Comment: @ Norbert Schuch  I think it really depends how to define the word 'state' since for me state is something to describe our knowledge about a system. From this viewpoint, you are right that the density matrix does the work. But if we consider the Eof a mixed state, then it can only be achieved in one(or a small set of) specific realization of the mixed state.  For me then the density matrix is just to show that we do not have enough information to fully specify the configuration of the system so we only describe it by its upper/lower bounds. Of course Eof here does have a physical meaning.

Comment: For example in the ER=EPR conjecture, if two blackholes are constructed from particle pairs of mixed state. Then it might be the case that the Eof may only show the minimal possible size of the ER bridge but can not fully describe the geometrical structure of the ER bridge. Of course it's just my personal idea, I do not know if it's the case or not.

Comment: @X.Dong If you use spaces after the @, it does not work. -- EoF is a well-defined quantity for any mixed state, namely the mimum average entanglement to prepare it. But I am afraid I don't understand what your question is. You should try to be *more consise*, not keep extending your question!

Comment: Imagine a pure state as describing a single system. Then you could have a population of identically prepared systems and if they are identical they are all prepared with the same kind of pure state. Now imagine you flip a coin and prepare a different pure state depending on the outcome of the coin. Now if you use that same process to make a bunch of systems there is a classical probability of it bring in a particular pure state. That's what a density matrix is. It describes a population of systems. It is a generalization since you could always pick a pure state with 100% classical probability.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch What I mean by 'incomplete description' of a state with the example of ER bridge is that: Although the ER bridge is constructed by the particles in mixed state, but as a macroscopic object it should posses a stable structure physically, which is determined by the entanglement pattern of its purification. But the ambiguity in the density matrix can not help to 'pick' one specific entanglement pattern from all the possible realizations of the mixed state so we do not have a complete description of the structure of ERB from the density matrix. So I call it incomplete.

Comment: @Timaeus Yes I totally agree with your description of mixed state and density matrix. But I think there is a difference between how the wave function to describe a pure state and how the density matrix does on mixed states. Or pure states and mixed states are essentially different (obviously they have different state space and different geometries).

Comment: @X.Dong As far as I know, only Weinberg thinks a density matrix describes the actual state of the universe. To everyone else you either have this pure state or that pure state, like having a bag full of marbles that are some red and some blue. So you actually have a pure state just like you actually have a red marble or a blue marble. It isn't a state of the universe it is a description of your ignorance about the pure state. But your post is impossible to read. Are you trying to entangle two particles that are already themselves in mixed single particle states? Mixed just means ignorance.

Comment: @Timaeus No. I have the same definition of mixed state as you. Since mixed means ignorance, that's why Eof for pure states and Eof for mixed states do not have the same physical meaning. We can associate with the Eof of pure states with a geometric picture, but this does not work for the Eof of mixed states. So for me the Eof of mixed state is not that physically meaningful as the Eof of pure states.

Comment: @X.Dong If you are ignorant then you are ignorant. If there is geometry and you are ignorant then you are ignorant of the geometry. But a description of your ignorance is a different than the way the world is. Please rewrite your question to be clear instead of confusing.

Comment: @Timaeus That's exactly what I mean. The Eof of a pure state describes a geometric object, the Eof of mixed state can not provide us the same information. So Eof of mixed state is not as physical as the Eof of pure states. So it's incomplete compared with Eof of pure states. I am not saying density matrix is not the right description for mixed states, I am just thinking how to find the right way to understand the physical meaning of Eof of mixed states. For example, if Eof of mixed states is also geometrical, then the structure of it must be different from that of pure states.

Comment: @Timaeus In fact I mean for a pure state 2 qubit, Eof is a complete description of its entanglement pattern (upto LUs). But for 2 qubit mixed state, its entanglement property should not be just its Eof. Given its Eof does not tell us too much about its entanglement pattern. Sorry for my confusing problem.

Comment: @X.Dong For a pure state of 2 qubits, this is true, but already for a pure state of 2 qutrits it is not.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch Do you mean the Eof as a complete description of entanglement for 2 qutrit is not true? I agree. My main point is to say the entanglement of mixed states seems to have no clear geometrical picture as in pure states. I am wondering how to understand entanglement of mixed state from a geometrical point of view. Do you have any suggestions on this? Thanks.